# time machine refuses to backup to time capsule

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

I'm trying to backup my hard drive to the time capsule, but it gives me the following error:

```
Time Machine couldn’t complete the backup to “aaragon's Time Capsule”.
The backup disk is not available. Make sure the backup disk is connected or select a different backup disk.

Latest successful backup: March 19, 2015
```

I don't know what to do as I've tried everything on [this support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18844?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) and [on this one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204157). I use dual backup so I have two disks (see picture).
[image]

Comment: It looks like it is out of space?

Comment: How is 261 GB available "out of space"??

Comment: Isn't the time capsule supposed to delete old backups to make space for new ones?